# Why this unexpected behaviour of od (octal dump)?

Tags: command-line

I have a text file called abc.txt containing

```
ABCDE
abcde
```

when I run `od -txc abc.txt` I get the following output:

```
0000000        44434241        62610a45        0a656463        0000000a
          A   B   C   D   E  \n   a   b   c   d   e  \n  \n
0000015
```

What I don't get is why order of the hex codes is reversed
every 4 bytes.  Is this just standard or is my command syntax
wrong?  I have used od on other versions of unix and I don't
recall ever seeing anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably formerly you were on a big-endian machine, and now on a little-endian.  You can swap the "endian" with the --endian=big option.